Formatting problem after using addStyle to apply style in excel
When I called addStyle to apply style in excel, say, column A in sheet1, was asked to be number. the targeted range was formatted fine.
However, after I open excel file, I saw all column A in other sheets, sheet 2, 3, 4
, which were originally date values, were all automatically changed into number.
I had to manally change them back to 'date' to be able to move to next step.
That really impact a lot of the calculation.
I checked all the logic and define ranges and can't find any mistake.
Can someone tell me why is this and how to kill it?
excel formatting things that was unwanted.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
